# Set Dropdown value to null when Page Loads MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dropdownlistfor

I have created a DropDwonList in MVC like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Item2.DeliveryDetail.PackageTypeId, new SelectList(lstPackageTypes, "PackageTypeId", "PackageTypeName"),new {@class = "cstm-input", @placeholder = "Package Type"})
```

It generates a DropDown but by default the first Item is selected when page loads. I want that the dropdown should be un-selected and the user should be allowed to select a value from it.

Thanx in Advance.

Comment: Use the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor``2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper{``0},System.Linq.Expressions.Expression{System.Func{``0,``1}},System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable{System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem},System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary{System.String,System.Object}%29) that add a `labelOption` - e.g. `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x...., new SelectList(..), "-please select-", new { ...})`

Comment: @StephenMuecke It is an answer.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Thanx for the help. If you want you can post this as an answer so that i could accept it as one. Else i have to mark Bhushan's answer.

Comment: @BhushanFirake has already added it so accept that :)

Comment: Ok No Probz, Thanx for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the default OptionLabel with overload method of [DropDownListFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%7D,System.String,System.Object%29) as below:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Item2.DeliveryDetail.PackageTypeId, 
 new SelectList(lstPackageTypes, "PackageTypeId", "PackageTypeName"),
 "--Select Package Type--",
 new {@class = "cstm-input", @placeholder = "Package Type"})
```